# Passing variables into the function to have server recognize category and id

Tags: jquery, grails

**html**

```
<a class="bookmarkit" herf="#modalBookmark" role="button" data-id="${image.id}" data-type="image">Bookmark</a>
<div id="modalBookmark" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header pure-u-1">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="icn-close-modal"></i></a>
    <h3 class="t-center">Add to Bookmark List</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body pure-u-1 log-body">

    <div class="bookmark-new">
      <form class="pure-form pure-g frm-add-list">
        <div class="pure-u-5-6"><input name="list" type="text" /></div>
        <div class="pure-u-1-6"><button class="pure-button btn-cromly btn-add-list">Add</button></div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="bookmark-list-wrapper">

    </div>
    <div class="bookmark-actions">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="pure-button btn-cromly btn-add" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Save</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
 var entryid = $('.bookmarkit').data('id');
    var category = $('.bookmarkit').data('type');
    $('#modalBookmark')
        .appendTo(document.body)
        .on('shown', function() {

            getBookmarks(userId, entryid);


        });

    $('.btn-add-list').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var bookmarkName = $('.bookmark-new input[name="list"]').val();
        console.log(bookmarkName);
        var bookmark = {
            ownerId: userId,
            name: bookmarkName
        };
        addBookmark(bookmark);

    });

    $('.bookmark-list-wrapper').on('click', '.bookmark-link', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        addBookmarkItem($(this), category, entryid, $(this).parent().attr('data-bookmark-id'));
    });



    function getBookmarks(userID, itemID) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/bookmarks',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                ownerId: userID,
                itemId: itemID,

            },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);

                $('.bookmark-list-wrapper').html(can.view('/views/bookmarks/bookmarks.ejs', {
                    bookmarks: response
                }));

            }
        });
    }

    function addBookmark(bookmarkObj) {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/bookmarks',
            type: 'POST',
            data: bookmarkObj,
            success: function(response) {
                $('.bookmark-list').prepend(can.view('/views/bookmarks/bookmark.ejs', {
                    bookmark: response
                }));
            }
        });
    }



    function addBookmarkItem(btn, category, itemID, bookmarkID) {
        var sendData = {
            ownerId: userId,
        };

        console.log('?: ' + $.param(sendData));

        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/bookmarks/' + bookmarkID + '?' + category +"="+ itemID + $.param(sendData),
            type: 'PUT',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                btn.addClass('active');
                btn.find('.count').text(response.items.length);
            }
        });
    }
```

`url: '/api/bookmarks/' + bookmarkID + '?' + category +"="+ itemID + $.param(sendData)`, seems not to be right..

dynamic get data-type for catagory, ie portfolio, image, etc and get data-id for the entry id. then grails (controller) would check if category is specified, then they would pass it to the bookmark function:
1) get the category, entry id, userid.
2) pass them to the function to show, display the list etc.

now i want the bookmark to be updated in bookmark list for specific category with entry-id and user-id. 
for example : http:/bookmarks?portfolio=123&userId=7
I tried to figure the way but I get the errors so I pasted without the changes.

***Update***

Error I see on console.log - (Unprocessable Entity). Not sure what it is. 
When the addBookmarkItem button is clicked, the bookmark will be marked for entry id and category.

Is there a way to get /bookmarks?portfolio=123&userId=7 working in correct way?

In case if you need to see bookmark api controller:

```
def update(Bookmark bookmark) {
    log.debug "Updating bookmark - bookmark=${bookmark}, params=${params}"

    if (params.image) {
        bookmark.addToImages(params.image)
    } else if (params.portfolio) {
        bookmark.addToPortfolios(params.portfolio)
    } else if (params.catalogue) {
        bookmark.addToCatalogues(params.catalogue)
    }

    try {
        println " Validate? " + bookmark.validate()
        bookmark.save(failOnError:true, flush:true)
    } catch (e) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        log.error e
        respond e
        return
    }

    def item = [:]
    item.name = bookmark.name
    item.id = bookmark.id
    item.items = bookmark.items ?: []
    item.portfolios = bookmark.portfolios ?: []
    item.added = true
    portfolios=${bookmark.portfolios}" 

    respond item 
}
```

Comment: what are you trying an which errors do you get ?

Answer (score 0):

when you pass a variable via the model to your view e.G

```
def bookmarkId = "fooBar"
render(view: 'myView', model:[bookmarkId: bookmarkId])
```

then you could pass it into your javascript like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        <g:if test="${bookmarkId}">
        url: '/api/bookmarks/${bookmarkId}?' + category +"="+ itemID + $.param(sendData),
        </g:if>
        <g:else>
        url: '/api/bookmarks/?' + category +"="+ itemID + $.param(sendData),
        </g:else>
        type: 'PUT',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            btn.addClass('active');
            btn.find('.count').text(response.items.length);
        }
    });
```

you can use "normal" gsp-scripting to check whether a condition matches or not etc.

maybe you get an idea

cheers

Comment: There is bookmark controller which is generated by Grails already. but is url coded correctly such as in http://bookmarks?image=123&ownerId=78?

Comment: you can go into that controller and take a look ? i just made some example code for you to get an idea, you can do whatever you like to do for example dont even do a request at all if theres no bookmarkId at all, just move the g:if a bit up ;)

Comment: I am not familiar with controller itself, but only work with jquery to make it work lol. I will try to follow your example and see if it works. thanks